# Grails AOP with aspectj and/or Groovy AOP preferably using annotations

Tags: grails, groovy, aspectj, abstract-syntax-tree

In our enterprise app, we would like to put cross cutting concerns like logging, metricing as aspects. We already have the aspectj advices ready(from our existing java app) but I am not finding a way to integrate aspectj with Grails.

I am already aware of `beforeInterceptor` and `afterInterceptor`, but these need to be done in  all Controllers and Services, is there an easier way to do this.

My preferred approach would be to create annotations for e.g `@Metrics` on any method in my grails application and it should get adviced. Has anyone done this, any links/resources/examples would be great to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at Grails *Filters* which can be used for cross cutting concerns such as logging etc:
http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html

Regarding using of annotations, maybe this article could be helpful, but I haven't checked it:
http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/03/15/simple-aspects-using-annotations-in-grails/

Best of luck.